# html table in php error

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

This is my code

```
if ($result!==false) {
$html_table =<table align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" width="1000" word-wrap="break-word" display="inline-block">
<tr><th>Bank</th><th>Projects</th><th>Status</th><th>PS Lead</th><th>Support</th><th>Remarks</th></tr>';

    foreach($result as $row){

    $html_table .= '<tr><td>' .$row["bankname"]. '</td><td>' .$row["bpiproject"]. '</td><td>' .$row["bpistatus"]. '</td><td>' . $row["bpips"] . '</td><td>' . $row["bpisupport"] .  '</td><td>' . $row["bpiremarks"] . '</td></tr>';

    }
}

 $conn = null;
 $html_table .= '</table>';
 echo $html_table;
```

and the error message says

> Undefined variable: html_table in line 33

which is

```
$html_table .='</table>';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: You're got your quote marks all wrong. You need a quote right after `$html_table = `

Comment: Also, you should set borders, alignment, etc. using `style= ...`

Comment: I already used this code in my other file and it works. but when I copy-pasted it, the error occur

Comment: missing opening quote from the `$html_table` initial string

Comment: still the same even I already put the opening qoute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you are starting your table inside an `if`, which means if your condition is not met then the code inside `if` will not run.

 
another is you are starting your variable string without `'` after `$html_table`
Do this

```
$html_table = "";
if ($result!==false) {
$html_table ='<table align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" width="1000" word-wrap="break-word" display="inline-block">
<tr><th>Bank</th><th>Projects</th><th>Status</th><th>PS Lead</th><th>Support</th><th>Remarks</th></tr>';

foreach($result as $row){

$html_table .= '<tr><td>' .$row["bankname"]. '</td><td>' .$row["bpiproject"]. '</td><td>' .$row["bpistatus"]. '</td><td>' . $row["bpips"] . '</td><td>' . $row["bpisupport"] .  '</td><td>' . $row["bpiremarks"] . '</td></tr>';

}
 $html_table .= '</table>';
}

 $conn = null;

 echo $html_table;
```

basically i have added `$html_table = "";` before `if` condition and `$html_table .= '</table>';` inside if condition. When your `if` condition is not met it will print blank `$html_table`

Comment: nothing. there's no more error but nothing shows on the screen

Comment: that means your `$result!==false` condition is not met. `$result` is `false` so the code inside the block is not executed.

Comment: what is `$result`? what does it return `var_dump($result)` before `if` condition, and make sure that it is returning what you desire

Comment: I did this $result==false and the table appeared! :) but there's an error saying "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: please `var_dump($result)` and see what is the output

Comment: I put that before the if ($result!==false) and it says Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Comment: you are missing `;` after `var_dump($result)`.

Comment: oh sorry. here's the result bool(false) 
Notice: Undefined variable: html_table

Comment: you are not getting any value in `$result`. Therefore you cannot use that value in `foreach`.

Comment: can you show code how `$result` is used before `if` condition?

Comment: $result = $conn->query($sql);

var_dump($result);
if ($result!==false)--------

Comment: actually I already used this code in other php file, it works. I copy-pasted it then there's an error

Comment: simple copy and paste will not work. you have to check if `$conn` or database connection is working and debug in procedural manner.